# Adding two objects with one django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, primary-key, increment

Just to mention, English is not my native language.
So my question is, I have a form in Python/Django, that adds a simple object with name and function, example:
Function: programmer
Name: Carlos
What I want to do is to make things simple for the user when he adds several users with the same function, so I thought, when the user do something like this...
Function: programmer
Name: Dean,Seth,Roman,Ross,Joey,Chandler
...my form would add 6 objects, but the problem is that when I do this, python/django always tries to use the same ID/PK(example: tries to add all 6 members with id/pk=1).
I've done a little manuever(in Brasil we call gambiarra), so my code does this(after splitting objects):
form2.name = nombre
form2.pk = primary+1
form2.save()
primary=form2.pk
This basically consists in using this var called primary to change the value of PK and saving to Postgres. It worked, now Dean is pk/id 1....Chandler is pk/id 6, and all in one form.
But, I'm not that lucky, so when I go to add another name, like George, the system tries to use pk=2.
Does anyone knows to resolve this thing without this manuever or how to improve this manuever to solve completely?

My code (just to remind, I'm a python beginner):
objnet = form.save(commit=False)
       if ',' in objnet.netaddr:
               listaips = objnet.netaddr.split(',')
               codeon = 1
               nomecomum=objnet.nome
               for ip in listaips:
                     objnet.netaddr = ip
                     objnet.nome = nomecomum + "_" + str(codeon)
                     objnet.save()
                     codeon+=1
       else:
                    objnet.save()

Explanation:
I have a form with an IP field(netaddr) and a char field(nome)....if contains a ',' in IP field, it will add more than one object, example:
nome = carlos
netaddr = 2.2.2.2,3.3.3.3
it should add carlos_1 in my DB with IP 2.2.2.2, and carlos_2 with IP 3.3.3.3. And the code really does that, but, he adds carlos_1 and then, he tries to add carlos_2, he does with the same PK, so instead of adding another element, he overwrites carlos_1, so in my DB now there's only carlos_2.

Thank you

Comment: Why would you be assigning PKs manually at all? They should be set by your database. You should never need to assign them.

Comment: Yeah, that was a crazy manuever I admit, but in a way I'll have to change it, because otherwise Django will try to add several objects with the same PK, and obviously will either replace my data or give me a PK error.

Comment: Well you'll need to show the full code. I have no idea what you're doing here.

Comment: Ok, let's go. I remove this manuever that I did and let the basic code, it's better start over than try to fix this mess....

Comment: I posted in a form of answer, so the code is more clear. Hope you understand and thanks for answering.

Comment: You should edit your question and place the code there. And please use proper formatting: there is a full explanation of how to do it, and even buttons to help.

Comment: Now please fix the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You have such problem because `objnet` always link to one object (since `form.save()` returns object)

Quick fix:

```
if ',' in objnet.netaddr:
    listaips = objnet.netaddr.split(',')
    codeon = 1

    for ip in listaips:
        objnet = form.save(commit=False)
        objnet.netaddr = ip
        objnet.nome = objnet.nome + "_" + str(codeon)
        objnet.save()

        codeon+=1
else:
    form.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but still didn't work. I tried to save two objects with the name abc, and the only one it was saved was abc_2 (so I'm guessing still used the same PK and overwrited in DB)